# What determines how much XP I earn, and how can I earn more?

Tags: tribes-ascend

With my wallet thin and weapon prices so high, I'm looking for faster ways to farm XP.

What exactly determines how much XP you get at the end of a match and what should you do to get more?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply put, the best way to farm XP is to **play games** and **win them**.

The XP you earn by playing is determined by three things: How long you were in the game, your position on the scoreboard, and whether your team won or lost.

### Base XP

First, you earn **Base XP** based on the amount of time you spent playing, at a rate of 0.5833/second. (Time spent waiting to respawn doesn't count.)

*Example*: You spent ten minutes of the match in-game, so you earn **350 Base XP**.

### Bonus XP

Next, you earn **Bonus XP** based on who won and how well you played. This value starts at 1/4 of your Base XP, and is divided by your position on the scoreboard. Everyone on the winning team gets their Bonus XP doubled. Any [badges (achievements)](http://wiki.theexiled.pwnageservers.com/Tribes:_Ascend/Badges) and first-win-of-the-day bonuses get added here as well.

*Example*: If you were second on your team, you would earn `(350 / 4) / 2` = **43 Bonus XP**. Since your team won, this would be doubled to **86 Bonus XP**. The first win of the day bonus increases that to **1286 Bonus XP**.

### VIP/Boost

Finally, you earn **VIP** and **Boost** bonuses based on the total thus far. If you have made any real-money purchase, you get a VIP bonus of (Base+Bonus * 0.5). If you are boosted, you earn another bonus of (Base+Bonus * 1.5). Effectively, being a boosted VIP triples the XP you earn.

*Example*: You are a VIP and boosted, so you earn an additional **818 VIP Bonus** and **2454 Boost Bonus**. All together, you earned 3,272 XP for this match.

Comment: This brings up another point: Because buying GP *once* makes you a VIP *permanently*, you should spend a few dollars on GP so you can benefit from the extra XP thereafter.

Comment: @echoback Nice try, High-Rez Studio

Comment: @echoback That's a very good point. I found buying just enough gold for a 30-day boost a much better option than spending gold on weapons directly, because you rake in XP like *crazy*.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is one answer to this question and most of it you could probably figure out.

But here are some pointers:

- Get the "first win of the day" First win of the day gives you 1200 xp
- Buy something, buying something gives you VIP status which is +50% for life
- Bonus XP, if you but $10 worth of gold, you get +50% XP. You can then use that to buy a 10 days booster, which gives +100% XP (on top of the 50%).
- All this means First win of the day pays out 3600 xp
- Team play wins the day

Gameplay pointers CTF:

- Find a role that you are good at (duh :P). Eg. if you are great at capping, this will give a lot of XP
- Usually the best ways of getting XP are capping (esp. going very fast doing so) and defending the flag and returning it
- Gene defender or attacking can be good too, if the generator is under heavy attack/defense and you can take out some

Not sure if this helps, as making XP in a game is really up to if you win and have a good match.

You can also check this page for some details:

http://www.tribesascendwiki.com/XP

Answer (score 1):

### Free Play

Base XP is accumulated at 0.5833 xp per second.  This is the same as 35 xp per minute and also the same as 2100 xp per hour.

Bonus xp modifier is a combination of two factors:

1. Did you win?  Winning is a 25% modifier.
2. How high did you place on the score board?  Divide 25% by your place on the score board to get the bonus.

Here is a list of the scoreboard modifier:

```
1st place = 25%
2nd place = 12.5%
3rd place = 8.33%
4th place = 6.25%
5th place = 5%
6th place = 4.16%
...
10th place = 2.5%
...
15th place = 1.66%
```

Add these two modifiers together to get your Bonus modifier.

```
Winning + FirstPlace = 50%
Losing + 15th place = 1.66%
```

So, to maximize xp - you want to be in long games (minimize map loading time), in which you win and place highly on the scoreboard.

Do not confuse Credits with XP, they have nothing to do with each other.  Credits are awarded during map play and disappear at the end of the match.  They are used to upgrade base equipment, buy vehicles and call in support (3, 4, 5).  Credits do not influence xp.

In particular - if you are a good flag runner, that is the worst thing you can do for your xp since it's just going to end the map and start another 0 xp map load.  It's better for xp to assault the enemy gens/defense, or stop their flag carrier as these actions extend the map while also contributing to your score.

```
Winning a five minute game in first place = 175 (base) * 1.5 (bonus) = 262 xp
Winning ten of them = 2625 and takes 55 minutes due to map loading time.
Losing a 55 minute game in 15th place = 1925 (base) * 1.0166 (bonus) = 1957 xp
```

Sum up:  Win when you can.  Score high always (being on small teams helps).  Play long games to minimize map loading.

### Money!

You get VIP status by purchasing any amount of gold.  This gives you a permanent 50% bonus on Base and Bonus xp.

You can also purchase Boosters which give you an additional doubling of Base, Bonus and VIP.

How you play doesn't influence these modifiers.  So the play strategy doesn't change from the freeplay.

```
Winning a five minute game in first place with VIP status =
  175 (base) * 1.5 (bonus) * 1.5 (VIP) = 393 xp.
Winning a five minute game in first place with boost active =
  175 (base) * 1.5 (bonus) * 1.5 (VIP) * 2 (Boost) = 787 xp
  which is triple the free rate.
```

The big question, I'm going to leave open - Is a booster worth it?  Why go for an xp bonus when you could just use the gold to unlock the thing you want?  Consider waiting for sales (items/roles for discounted gold prices).  Consider forecasting the minutes you'll play while the boost is active and calculating the xp that gold expenditure will give you.