# What should I buy for my first XP?

Tags: tribes-ascend

I have played Tribes a couple of hours and and decided to buy the [Starter Pack](http://store.steampowered.com/app/17095/) on Steam. What should I buy with my first XP? What should I avoid?

Comment: Edited your post, assuming you meant to say "efficient" and not "effective".

Comment: This is a partial duplicate of a question already asked here: [What determines how much XP I earn, and how can I earn more?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/65792/274) You might want to rephrase your post and remove the first bullet point. :)

Comment: Frank, considering your two questions are completely different, and most of the existing answers focused on your first question, I think it would be best to simply create a new question asking for "which items should I spend my first XP on"

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft we asked Frank to revise his question and he did.  Please don't start an edit war.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What items should I spent my first XP on?

Based on cost, it would appear the designers of the game intend for you to unlock new classes, then a few talents, then a few weapons.  By the time you've done this, you'll probably know what you want to spend xp on.

I would avoid spending any xp upgrading items.  Those upgrades can be earned through play and it doesn't take very long.

Since you bought the Starter Pack, you already have the Infiltrator and the Technician.  Doombringer is a solid next choice.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on your play. Are you happy/comfortable with your current classes you have unlocked? Are you enjoying certain classes more? For me, I started out playing Pathfinder and quickly leveled up nearly everything in it, so I am currently at 74%. With the XP I gained whilst doing this, I bought more gear for it and nabbed a couple classes when they were on sale.

Basically, I guess you should watch some YouTube footage and decide which class(es) are your favorite. If it so happens to be one of your already-owned ones, then start piling the XP into upgrades and gear!

Answer (score 2):

The first purchase that I made on the day of release was the Doombringer class.  While I concede that Juggernaut is an excellent source of disruption for flag defense, all it takes is *one* individual with no skill to take you down, provided they have a lot of ammo in reserve (for automatic weapons) or have a good trigger finger (for spinfusors or sniper rifles).

The Doombringer brings a few things to the table: mainly flag defense.  It is a massive class like the Juggernaut, but is great at flag defense and the initial few moments after your flag gets snatched.  Your job is to be the "HOF", or "heavy on flag" (you're a heavy class, and you stand on the flag...simple!).  Place mines strategically and DO NOT stand on them - doing so will kill you, more often than not.  I usually place a mine in front of me, behind me, and one off to the side if enemy flag runners (Pathfinders) have a route that comes in from that direction.  Then you stand there with your chain gun and fire repeatedly; aim slightly above the persons head as they are climbing higher in the sky, and aim at their crotch as they are descending on your flag, and you'll hit them the entire time...it only takes a few seconds before they die, as they can't change direction and smack right into you.

The other thing Doombringer has is it's Force Field - drop it in front of or behind the flag until you learn better places to put it.  In the previous example, if you missed some shots and the Pathfinder going for your flag is still alive, he or she will smack right into that force field and die.  It also soaks up enemy fire so you can hide behind it until your shields repair (keep in mind that explosions will still hit you if you are standing nearby).

The SABER missile launcher is great for catching vehicles (especially in the air), but is also great at catching players as they ramp up hills.  just keep left-clicking as it stays locked on.  While a lot of people frown upon the use of the SABER against Pathfinders, I find that it is *always* worth it to "try" to hit them.  Most Pathfinders will just outrun the SABER and it will detonate on it's own or get shot down, but if the enemy carrier makes a mistake and bumps into something, or slows down...it's an easy kill and your teammates who are chasing the carrier can return the flag for you.

And on top of all this...you can get the "Heavy" perk for use on flag defense.  It makes you much heavier by increasing your mass, so you don't get tossed around as much when explosions throw you to the side...this is very important as most flag carriers come in and shoot with their spinfusor at the flag stand to detonate any of your mines and to push you off of it.  As this levels up, you also become so heavy that enemies take damage from bumping into you - which is great.  Stand there, flag carrier runs into you, dies, and you auto-return the flag (or it will be right behind you).  I have found that this works just as well when you are standing in their base and they rush in to defend...just run into them ;-)

I hope this helps.  Each class has it's job, but at least in this way you can get the basics of firing learned while also doing something helpful for your team - defending the flag.  Just remember to take cover when tactical strikes are initiated on top of where you're standing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

My answer is to either upgrade your favorite class or buy new ones to play with
I would recommend trying out weapons and classes in training mode before you buy them so you don't buy the class or weapon/skill and later on don't use the class